# How to Calculate F distribution given R squared?

Tags: regression, r-squared, f-distribution

After some research, I find that the relationship between $R^2$ and the F distribution is as follows:

$$
R^2 = 1 - (1 + F \cdot \frac{p-1}{n-p})^{-1}
$$

But I am not sure what the $p$ and $n$ values should be. Suppose my $R^2$ is calculated from 10 values of $x$ and $y$, what would $p$ and $n$ be?

Thanks!

EDIT: don't think it's a duplicate because my question is more basic, i.e. what $p$ and $n$ values are.

Comment: p is the number of parameters in model

Comment: @Hamed thanks for the answer, can you explain what parameters are? for example in a linear regression with one variable, are there two paramters (intercept and slope)? also is n the number of observations then?

Comment: yes, for example if you have a model like $Y=b_0+b_1X_1+\ldots+b_kX_k$ then $p=k+1$. Yes n is the number of observations in response, y.

Comment: You were right that it wasn't really a duplicate. I clarified one of the answers in the linked "duplicate" to define the terms $n$ and $p$ (that should have been defined there).